# Magento Store - Don't Send Newsletter Success Email

Tags: magento

When users subscribe to the newsletter on A Magento Store they receive a confirmation email.  Is it possible to prevent this email from being sent?

There doesn't seem to be an option in the back end for this.

Comment: don't need to install extenuation and make load on site.
go to  
\app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_success.html  
put full page in comment .
and from now you don't get any mail on news later subscription.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a module that solves this, and can be enabled and disabled from the backend.

[Module configuration screenshot](http://cl.ly/4na2)

[Download the module](http://cl.ly/4nCz)

Comment: If you have the time it would be a really nice gesture to submit this to Magento Connect for others to download.

Comment: +1 This module is a nice way of preventing the success email if you are using the Fontis Campaign Monitor extension to handle the newsletter subscriptions (meaning you don't want Magento really getting involved at all in emailed confirmations).

Comment: don't need to install extenuation and make load on site.
go to  
\app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_success.html  
put full page in comment .
and from now you don't get any mail on news later subscription.

Comment: newslater menu not work in this extentation . conflict some with other part in default magento store also . plz make it good

Answer (score 9):

The file you want to override is `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber`. Create a class that overrides that model, and then replace two methods like this:

```
<?php

class Somepackage_Somemodule_Models_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber {

    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function sendUnsubscriptionEmail() {
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

This will disable newsletter subscription (and unsubscription) emails to customers.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe.  Where exactly should I place this code?  In the Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber file?

Cheers!

Comment: I think Joe was saying that you should create your own module.  If you haven't done that before do some google searches on how to create a magento module.  I will also mention that if you follow Joe's suggestion, your module's config.xml file will need to include a rewrite of Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber.  See this link to find out how to do that: http://www.exploremagento.com/magento/override-a-magento-core-block-class.php

Answer (score 2):

For disabling any email notification in Magento you can use my [free extension](https://magery-themes.com/disable-email-notifications.html) for Magento 1.

Also, there is [similar extension](https://magery-themes.com/disable-email-notifications-magento2.html) for Magento 2.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean success or confirmation (need to confirm to get newsletter) email?

The latter can be switched off in Configuration->Newsletter

Comment: I mean the success email.  I have already turned the confirmation off in admin.

Answer (score -3):

A much easier way, although it is kind of a hack, is to look for the method sendConfirmationSuccessEmail which sends the emails. It is found in:

app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

The only thing you gotta do is to put a return true at the first line of the method.